# Terminate servicestack service on web request

Tags: servicestack

I am wondering if there is a way to terminate hosted as a console servicestack service on a web request?

I tried windows forms application with embedded browser but it feels much slower than google chrome. So my plan is to run a console application in a background and terminate it on user action in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call `Environment.Exit(0);` to quit the .NET Application. To increase the perceived performance just hide the Window before you exit, e.g:

```
formMain.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() =>
{
    formMain.Hide();
    formMain.Close();
});
```

I highly recommend checking out the new [React Desktop Apps](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/ReactDesktopApps) template which automatically includes running ServiceStack embedded inside a Chromium browser in a Winforms App, an OSX Cocoa App as well as a cross-platform Win/Linux/OSX Console App.

The [React Chat Apps](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/ReactChatApps) Example App does exactly what you're after, i.e. closing the App from a Webservice request to quit the running application. Here's a [YouTube demo of it in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9kVqdPbqOM&feature=youtu.be) that shows quiting multiple Window Application instances from a Web Service Request.